# opendkim[8143]: initgroups(): Operation not permitted

Tags: postfix-mta, dkim

I have configure Opendkim with Postfix and configured everything as per the document referred multiple sites. But finally got the below error.

`opendkim[8143]: initgroups(): Operation not permitted`

Could anyone help on this fix the same. As i googled for the same and haven't found any solution.

Thanks

Comment: can you share opendkim.conf?

Comment: Did you fix this issue? Because I'm facing the same issue!

Comment: Yes, it was happened due to the opendkim ports for clients were not allowed in the iptables.. when I allowed that one this was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it chrooted, check that the user the service is running under is the same as defined in conf and added to relevant groups. Chrooted usually define opendkim to be ran as "postfix:postfix" user. You'll have to create folders under /var/spool/postfix/ for opendkim to hold socket file, add postfix user to opendkim group

postfix/main.cf:

```
smtpd_milters = unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock unix:/var/run/opendmarc/opendmarc.sock
non_smtpd_milters = ${smtpd_milters}
```

opendkim.conf:

```
Socket                  local:/var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

ls:

```
root@s1:/etc/postfix# ls -la /var/spool/postfix/var/run/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 postfix postfix 4096 Dec 31 09:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 postfix postfix 4096 Dec 22 13:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 postfix postfix 4096 Dec 22 14:07 opendkim
drwxr-xr-x 2 postfix postfix 4096 Dec 31 09:28 opendmarc
```